# What is the performance impact of saving and fetching fractional double field data in postgres database

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, double

What is the performance impact of using “fraction data fields” vs. “regular number field” in Postgres?

For instance:
The numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Vs.
The numbers: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8

I would like mainly to sort according to this field and sometimes to filter.

Thanks,
Shay

Comment: What do you mean by "regular number field" and "fractional number field"? Are you trying to compare the performance of `integer` (ie `int4`) with `float`? `int8` with `double`? `numeric`? Also... PostgreSQL version please - `select version()`. Always specify your PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Yes, I would like to compare int, float and double. We use postgres 9.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference between `int` and `float` in PostgreSQL will be extremely minimal. To confirm this yourself I strongly recommend that you write some custom pgbench scripts that exersise the same workload, once with `integer` and once with `float`. You'll find that other costs - disk I/O, for one thing - greatly outweigh any cost differences between `float` and `int`.

There can be a fairly significant difference between the low level types like `int` and `float` vs the higher-level type `numeric`, which is a software decimal type with nearly unlimited precision and scale.

Try it and see; you'll quickly confirm that the performance difference between `integer` and `float` is tiny in PostgreSQL - on common hardware, at least.